# undefined reference to `PerformChat(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*)

Tags: c++, compilation, chatscript

I want to use ChatScript externally in my program. In the [documents](https://github.com/bwilcox-1234/ChatScript/blob/master/WIKI/CLIENTS-AND-SERVERS/ChatScript-External-Communications.md) it says:

> #### Embedding Step #1 First, you will need to modify `common.h and compile the system. You need to add all the CS .cpp files to your build list.
>
> Find the `// #define NOMAIN 1` and uncomment it. This will allow you to compile your program as the main program and ChatScript merely as a collection of routines to accompany it.

But I am newbie in Linux and can’t understand how to add .cpp files to my build list? What is my build list? May someone explains what do should I do exactly?

I did copy all the .cpp and .h and other folders existed inside ChatScript/SRC directory beside my main.cpp in my project.

Then I tried to run this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

char* output2;
    unsigned int InitSystem(int argc,char* argv[],char* unchangedPath,char* readonlyPath,char* writablePath);
    void InitStandalone();
    void PerformChat(char* user,char* usee,char* incoming,char* ip,char* output);

    int main()
    {

    PerformChat(NULL,NULL,"hi",NULL,output2);

    cout<<output2;

        return 0;
    }
```

But I get this error message:

```
undefined reference to `PerformChat(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*)
```

Then I did include all the header files to my program and delete this line of code:        `void PerformChat(char* user,char* usee,char* incoming,char* ip,char* output);`

```
#include<iostream>

#include "common.h"
#include "common1.h"
#include "constructCode.h"
#include "cs_ev.h"
#include "csocket.h"
#include "dictionaryMore.h"
#include "dictionarySystem.h"
#include "english.h"
#include "evserver.h"
#include "factSystem.h"
#include "functionExecute.h"
#include "infer.h"
#include "jsmn.h"
#include "json.h"
#include "mainSystem.h"
#include "markSystem.h"
#include "mongodb.h"
#include "mprintf.h"
#include "multi.h"
#include "my_sql.h"
#include "os.h"
#include "outputSystem.h"
#include "patternSystem.h"
#include "postgres.h"
#include "privatesrc.h"
#include "scriptCompile.h"
#include "spellcheck.h"
#include "systemVariables.h"
#include "tagger.h"
#include "testing.h"
#include "textUtilities.h"
#include "tokenSystem.h"
#include "topicSystem.h"
#include "userCache.h"
#include "userSystem.h"
#include "variableSystem.h"

using namespace std;

char* output2;
    unsigned int InitSystem(int argc,char* argv[],char* unchangedPath,char* readonlyPath,char* writablePath);
    void InitStandalone();
    void PerformChat(char* user,char* usee,char* incoming,char* ip,char* output);

    int main()
    {

    PerformChat(NULL,NULL,"hi",NULL,output2);

    cout<<output2;

        return 0;
    }
```

But the new error says:

```
error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘int main()'
```

Comment: Uh oh. This source bundle comes with a Makefile that only supports building executables, not a library, and I don't see any header file appropriate for using it as a library. This isn't going to be simple, I'm afraid.

Comment: @aschepler: but it says `Find the // #define NOMAIN 1 and uncomment it. This will allow you to compile your program as the main program and ChatScript merely as a collection of routines to accompany it.`

Answer (score 1):

You would have to include all the chatscript SRC files in your project to get the function PerformChat to compile. But shortly ChatScript will release with library compilations as well.

Comment: you mean I must do #include all the .h files above my main function(below #include <iostream>) ?

Comment: May you explain more your short part?  `ChatScript will release with library compilations as well.`

Comment: I added all the header files but got new error: `error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘int main()`

Comment: I think as tutorial says I must compile the ChatScript before using it externally, but I can't do it :(

Comment: ChatScript releeases in the future will come with a DLL ready for use.

Comment: About files, currently the way to include chatscript in your project is to have your project and add all of chatscripts files to it as well (with #define NOMAIN 1)  so that all are compiled together.